# How to fix SSL Tunnel Failure when using Robo 3T to connect to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB Atlas database using Robo 3T following the directions at:

https://mrvautin.com/connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-with-robo-3t/

I get an SSL Tunnel Failure message as shown below:

[image: Robo 3T error]

I have verified that I can connect to this database from the command line using the Mongo shell:

[image: Mongo shell connection]

So it does not appear to be an issue with my firewall or whitelist settings. (for this database, the whitelist allows incoming connections from any IP address.)

I have tried using both "Direct Connection" and "Replica Set" as the "Type" in Robo 3T, but get the same error each time.

I am quite confident that I am supplying a correct username and password.

How do I diagnose and fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After chatting with the MongoDB tech support folks, I was able to finally determine how to solve this problem.  They have a page of documentation on connecting to Atlas using MongoDB here:

https://intercom.help/mongodb-atlas/en/articles/934375-connecting-to-atlas-using-robo-3t-formerly-robomongo

However, it was missing some crucial details which were provided to me by tech support.  I've documented the process more completely in this page:

http://courses.ics.hawaii.edu/ics314f19/morea/deployment/reading-atlas-robo3t.html

Comment: The "optional" that is not so "optional" got me. Thanks for the great blogpost!

Comment: The UI has changed since your post and there's no 'cluters' button unfortunately. What's worse is that MongoDB serverless is now in preview mode and I think connecting to it is even more different than here but this guide is detailed so it's a start!

Answer (score 1):

I've taken an example from @phillps answer and write down steps for **Studio 3T**

few steps are different but almost all are the same

For more details refer to this link.

https://link.medium.com/aB51KetjD9

Comment: you shouldn't take credit for "chatting with their tech support people" when you weren't the one who did it. That was from @Philip Johnson's post

Comment: The 'clusters' button has been removed from the page! If you know where else to find it that would be great to update your answer / medium post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it installing **Robo 3T 1.4.4 version**. You can download it from here: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases